# How to sort Hexadecimal Numbers (like 10 1 A B) in C?

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, hex

I want to implement a sorting algorithm in C for sorting hexadecimal numbers like:

```
10 1 A B
```

to this:

```
1 A B 10
```

The problem that I am facing here is I didn;t understand how A & B is less than 10 as A = 10 and B = 11 in hexadecimal numbers. Im sorry if I am mistaken.
Thank you!

Comment: 10 is not decimal it is hex. In decimal it is 16.

Comment: why tag C++ when you're asking about C?

Comment: is this a C++ or just C question?

Comment: Code in C and C++ both are accepted.

Comment: @AKHILSHARMA C and C++ are two different languages.  A solution in C++ may never work in C.

Comment: Let's see what [the tag info for c](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info) has to say: *" 'Either C or C++ is fine' opinions from the OP is a strong indication of a poor or unclear question. Answers may be very different depending on language picked. Prompt for clarification, close as unclear/too broad until the OP has clarified this."* -- hmm, that does not look like a good justification for using both tags.

Comment: Besides, it seems like your issue is understanding hexadecimal notation rather than a language-specific question. That is, you want to know how hexadecimal A (which equals decimal 10) can be less than hexadecimal 10, right? No coding involved there, just an explanation that hexadecimal 10 equals decimal 16.

Comment: Hexadecimal order = 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,A,B,C,D,E,F.  Where F is decimal value of 15.
Then digits start to double so 10 in hex, is then the next number up from F. (just like 10 is the next number up from 9 in decimal). So 10 hexadecimal is 16 decimal. To avoid confusion hexadecimal numbers in C and C++ are prefixed with 0x, so 0x10 == 16

Comment: Here is a bit of C++ code to play with, try different number sequences and see how they will be sorted so you can get a feel of what hex numbers do. https://www.onlinegdb.com/fork/tH6II-e0A

Comment: Here's the most important question.  Are you trying to sort numbers stored as type `int` or similar. Or are you trying to sort *hexadecimal strings* by value?

Comment: I think i am trying to sort hexadecimal strings by value.

Comment: @JaMiT Im sorry i thought that both the programming languages will have nearly same solution. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @JaMiT yes that's what i didn't understand can you please tell me where I can learn this. I was confused because I thought that hexadecimal are limited to F value which is 15. Can you please tell me a resource where I can find this?

Comment: _I thought that **hexadecimal** are limited to F..._ Hexadecimal what? Numbers or digits? "And what is the difference, where can I learn about this", you will ask.

Comment: Hello Jacon, i meant hexadecimals numbers. And yes where can I learn about this?

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the previous comments, 10 is 0x10, so this sorting seems to be no problem: 0x1 < 0xA < 0xB < 0x10

Comment: Hello thank you for your time. I don't know much about hexadecimal numbers but I did;t understand this representation of Hex Numbers. And We have this order of hex numbers right?: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F so B is greater than 10 right?

Comment: 0x0 0x1 0x2 0x3 0x4 0x5 0x6 0x7 0x8 0x9 0xA 0xB 0xC 0xD 0xE 0xF 0x10, 0x10 closely follows F, just like 16 follows 15 in decimal,so 0x10 > 0xB

Comment: 10 in hexadecimal is 16 in decimal.  Basically, if you're given this in hexadecimal, `31`, and you don't know it is equivalent to 49 in decimal, then I suggest you learn the basics of number bases and conversions.

Comment: Thank you @PaulMcKenzie for your help. That's what was tripping me. I didn't understand why we write 10 like this in hexadecimal. Can you help me with a resource where I can learn this thing? That will be a great help.

Comment: @AKHILSHARMA I suggest you start from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal (it's not a joke! it will allow you to see facts you already know in a broader context), then see the more general https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeral_system and finally a specific https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal

Answer (score 2):

In any base a number with two digits is always greater than a number with one digit.

In hexadecimal notation we have 6 more digits available than in decimal, but they still count as one "digit":

```
 hexadecimal digit | value in decimal representation
                 A | 10
                 B | 11
                 C | 12 
                 D | 13
                 E | 14
                 F | 15
```

When you get a number in *hexadecimal* notation, it might be that its digits happen to use none of the above extra digits, but just the well-known 0..9 digits. This can be confusing, as we still must treat them as *hexadecimal*. In particular, a digit in a multi-digit hexadecimal representation must be multiplied with a power of 16 (instead of 10) to be correctly interpreted. So when you get 10 as hexadecimal number, it has a value of one (1) time sixteen plus zero (0), so the hexadecimal number 10 has a (decimal) value of 16.

The hexadecimal numbers you gave should therefore be ordered as 1 < A < B < 10.

As a more elaborate example, the hexadecimal representation 1D6A can be converted to decimal like this:

```
  1D6A    
  │││└─>  10 x 16⁰ =   10
  ││└──>   6 x 16¹ =   96
  │└───>  13 x 16² = 3328
  └────>   1 x 16³ = 4096
                     ──── +
                     7530
```

Likewise

```
  10    
  │└─>   0 x 16⁰ =    0
  └──>   1 x 16¹ =   16
                     ── +
                     16
```